# Why is my convolutional Neural Network stuck in a local minimum?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mean-square-error

I've heard that machine learning algorithms rarely get stuck in local minima, but my CNN (in tensorflow) is predicting a constant output for all values and I am using a mean square error loss function so I think this must be a local minima given the properties of MSE. I have a network with 2 convolution layers and 1 dense layer (+1 dense output layer for regression) with 24, 32 and 100 neurons respectively, but I've tried changing the numbers of layers/neurons and the issue is not solved. I have relu activations for the hidden layers and absolute value on the output layer (I know this is uncommon but it converges faster to a lower MSE than the softplus function which still has the same problem and I need strictly positive outputs). I also have a 50% dropout layer between the dense and output layers and a pooling layer between the 2 convolutions. I have also tried changing the learning rate (currently 0.0001) and batch size. I am using an Adam Optimizer.

I have seen it suggested to change/add bias but I'm not sure how to initialize it in tf.layers.conv2d/tf.layers.dense (for which I have bias=True), and I can't see any options for bias with tf.nn.conv2d which I used for my first layer so I could initialize the kernel easily.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated, thanks.

Here's the section of my code with the network:

```
filter_shape = [3,3,12,24]
def nn_model(input):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, mean=10, 
stddev=3), name='weights')    
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=conv1, filters=32, kernel_size=[3,3], 
padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, 
padding='same')
    flat = tf.reshape(pool, [-1, 32*3*3])
    dense_3 = tf.layers.dense(flat, neurons, activation = tf.nn.relu)
    dropout_2 = tf.layers.dropout(dense_3, rate = rate)
    prediction = tf.layers.dense(dropout_2, 1, activation=tf.nn.softplus)    
    return prediction
```

My inputs are 5x5 images with 12 channels of environmental data and I have ~100,000 training samples. My current MSE is ~90 on values of ~25.

Comment: Can you share more details on your architecture? What size are your images? How many training samples do you have? What is your current accuracy? What hyperparameters are you using (exact learning rate, learning rate decay, optimizer,...)? Have you used batch normalization between the Conv layers? Also, why are you using different operations for the two convolutions? And what size is `filter_shape`?

Comment: Also I am not sure where you got the idea that ML algorithms "rarely get stuck in local minima". Literally every single neural network "gets stuck" in a local minima; only that most of the local minima are good enough. I think you are confusing the convexity of your loss function with the non-convexity of neural networks.

Comment: @dennlinger my inputs are just 5x5, but I could take them up to 7x7 which I suppose may help? I have about 100, 000 training samples and my current mean *square* error is about 90 on values of about 25. I haven't used batch norm mainly just because I never really understood what it was for. I'm using different operations just because I at first was using tf.layers but then I couldn't figure out how to initialize the weights so I switched the first layer (which was the only one I initialized) to tf.nn(although come to think of it I should probably initialize both), filter_shape=[3,3,12,24] :)

Comment: @ and yes thanks I know that you usually just get to a 'good enough' minima, but I've been told you usually don't get stuck in one which is far out which seems to be happening here.

Comment: Plesae add this information to your post, and not in the comments, so other users can find it easily. Also, I am not 100% sure, but I think `tf.layers` does some automatic initialization, or at least should do it. You also still haven't included any information on the important hyperparameters and optimizer.

Comment: Sorry yes done that now-and I'm using the Adam Optimizer. And thanks I'll look into that. I can't think of any more hyperparameters to include but please let me know if I've missed any.

Comment: Learning rate and batch size are generally something to mention. How many epochs (i.e. passes over your whole data) are you running? Do you decay your learning rate over time? Are you using a validation set to verify your results?

I mentioned some of these things already in earlier comments, please take the time to read carefully through them and add the information. Otherwise people will not be able to help you...

Comment: My learning rate has no decay and yes I am using a validation set with 20% of my data, training data being 60% and the remaining 20% left out for testing at the end. Sorry if I missed things out earlier.

Answer (score -1):

I used to face the same problem with bigger images. I incresed the number of convolution layers to solve it. Maybe you should try to add even more convolution layers.

In my opinion, the problem comes from the fact you don't have enough parameters and thus get stuck in a local minimum. If you increase your number of parameters, it can help the updates to converge to a better minimum.

Also, I can't see the optimizer you are using. Is it Adam ? You can try to start with a bigger learning-rate and use a decay to decrease it epoch after epoch.

Comment: "Adding more layers" is only something to say if you are really sure you have enough training data, and the parameter set is not enough to cover the complexity of the task.
In many cases, I see people throwing a network of ResNet-like sizes at a problem that could be solved with a single convolutional layer, and often outperforms a heavy-weight network due to the fact that it simply has *too many* parameters, and thus overfits way heavier.

Comment: Thanks! I added a few convolutional layers and another dense layer but it doesn't seem to have solved it (I've already tried going up to 3/4 of each). I had a similar problem before with a normal neural net and solved it by weight initialization but that doesn't seem to help this time. Might it help to add a regularizer?

Comment: Sorry just realised I didn't say...yes I'm using an Adam optimiser